# How can I make form and buttons inline?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**How can I inline align form with a button?**

**HTML**

```
<a href='games'><button><i class='fa fa-gamepad'></i></button></a>
<a href='settings'><button><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i></button></a>
<form action='../assets/php/logout_php.php' method='POST'>
   <button id='odhlaseni' type='submit' name='submit'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-off'></i></button>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
/*Just those buttons*/
div div button {
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline !important;
    padding-bottom: 1px !important;
    border: 2px solid #474747;
    color: #474747;
    background-color: transparent;

    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

/*Hover for those buttons*/
div div button:hover {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: #474747;
}
```

I have something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c4T4.jpg
1 = menu icon
2 = games
3 = settings
4 = my problem - logout button.
All I want is to align that fourth button next to third. I could do this easily with CSS margin-left and -top, but then it doesn't show properly on mobile devices. Then I tried just creating a button (which aligns perfectly next to number 2 and 3) but then I had a problem with sending ajax request to my logout.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a div and display it as a `flex`:

```css
/*Just those buttons*/
div div button {
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline !important;
    padding-bottom: 1px !important;
    border: 2px solid #474747;
    color: #474747;
    background-color: transparent;

    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

/*Hover for those buttons*/
div div button:hover {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: #474747;
}

.wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<a href='games'><button class='marginLeftGames'><i class='fa fa-gamepad'></i></button></a>
<a href='settings'><button><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i></button></a>
<form action='../assets/php/logout_php.php' method='POST'>
   <button id='odhlaseni' type='submit' name='submit'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-off'></i></button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: It created this https://imgur.com/a/LElKA
I think there must be a problem with my CSS, I'll look into, but if I remove flew-flow from .wrap it seems to be working on a desktop. Anyway thanks a lot! Oh well, I just found that I didn't remove my old CSS with that margin-left and -top method. It now works perfectly! Thanks a lot, sir!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap all of the buttons in containers with a column width.

Such as;

```
.btn-col {
  min-width: 24.75%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Then you could wrap each button in this and it should give them space, adjust width for amount of buttons.

If you are using a CSS framework, they will usually have this come with it, known as a 'grid layout'.

Comment: I've forgotten to mention that I already tried this, but it didn't suit my needs. Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: @AdriánZámečník fair enough, if you are writing your own CSS and want it to look good on mobile, tablet and PC look into media queries too.